# Hide action bar Android Studio in tabhost

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fullscreen, android-tabhost

I'm creating an Android application and there's a page like this, a weather page is held inside a tabhost:

[image: Interface]

The MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //I used this but it's not working
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(
            new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class)
    ));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(
            new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class)
    ));
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

And the SecondActivity contains the weather:

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new WeatherFragment())
                .commit();
    }


}
```

The problem is that I want to hide the actionbar <> as it looks really awful in this. As you can see that I tried to request FEATURE_NO_TITLE or set FLAG_FULLSCREEN, as well as set `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"` in AndroidManifest, but nothing works well.

(In addition, is there anyway to set the weather interface fullscreen? As it has a small gap between edges)
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Change `ActionBarActivity` to `Activity` in your `SecondActivity`.

```
public class SecondActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

to

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
```

And if this not give you the expected answer then add below in `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

Or in your `SecondActivity` add below:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity xml there is a layout called appbarlayout please delete it it will work.
 in my activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.ezybzy.Categorypage">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_categorypage" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

please change to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ezybzy.ezybzy.Categorypage">



    <include layout="@layout/content_categorypage" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this will work only if you create blank activity!!

Comment: It didn't work, I created an empty activity instead, thus there's no `<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` in my xml :(